# Java NullPointerException

Tags: java

Всем привет. Вот пытаюсь разобраться с массивами. Идея в том чтоб циклом создать 10 кнопок, и разместить их на панели. Кнопки хранятся в массиве. При запуске выбивает NullPointerException. Помогите разобраться)

```
package trening;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class massiv {
    JPanel window;
    JButton squares [];
    JPanel p1;
     massiv () {
    p1 = new JPanel();
         squares = new JButton [10];
         for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
        squares[i] = new JButton();
        squares[i].setVisible (true);
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout (4,3));
        p1.add(squares[i]);
        }

         window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         window.add("North", p1);
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("massiv");
         frame.setContentPane(window);

         frame.pack();

         frame.setVisible(true);
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     massiv mas = new massiv();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, JPanel window не инициализирована. Должно быть где-то в коде window = new JPanel();

Comment: точно) спасибо)) теперь будем вставлять названия на кнопки)

Comment: Не за что:)